# Standard error of the intercept scipy.stats.linregress

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, linear-regression

The function [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) automatically calculates the standard error of the fitted slope. How do I get the standard error of the fitted **intercept**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be to use the [`pyfinance.ols` module](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance/blob/master/pyfinance/ols.py#L281), which has separate standard error attributes for the intercept (alpha) and other coefficients.  Disclosure: I wrote this module.  It was uploaded to PyPI recently for easier install.

A quick example:

```
from pyfinance.ols import OLS

x = np.random.randn(50)
y = np.random.beta(1, 2, 50)
model = OLS(y=y, x=x)
model.se_alpha
# 0.029413047270740914
```

Under the hood, the class is adding a column vector of ones, and the alpha/intercept term is just a normal coefficient to this vector.  Unlike with statsmodels and sklearn, `.fit()` is effectively called at class instantiation.